# pandas: join two table and populate value when even there is not a match

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Not sure how should I describe the problem, so I will use an example below.
I want to join the following two table df1 and df2 to get a table like df3 where all IDs, A, B, C, D need to be present for each Time.

```
d1 = {'Time': [1,1,2,2], 'BinID': ['x']*4, 'V1': [25, 30, 22, 28], 'ID': ['A','B']*2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)  

  BinID ID  Time  V1
0     x  A     1  25
1     x  B     1  30
2     x  A     2  22
3     x  B     2  28

d2 = {'BinID': ['x']*4, 'ID': ['A','B','C','D'], 'V2': [26]*4}

df2= pd.DataFrame(d2)

  BinID ID  V2
0     x  A  26
1     x  B  26
2     x  C  26
3     x  D  26
```

I want to get something like this:

```
  BinID_x ID  V2 BinID_y  Time  V1
0       x  A  26       x     1  25
1       x  B  26       x     1  30
2       x  C  26       x     1 NaN
3       x  D  26       x     1 NaN 
4       x  A  26       x     2  22
5       x  B  26       x     2  28
6       x  C  26       x     2 NaN
7       x  D  26       x     2 NaN
```

But left join only gets me this...

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, on = 'ID', how = 'left')


  BinID_x ID  V2 BinID_y  Time  V1
0       x  A  26       x     1  25
1       x  A  26       x     2  22
2       x  B  26       x     1  30
3       x  B  26       x     2  28
4       x  C  26     NaN   NaN NaN
5       x  D  26     NaN   NaN NaN
```

Comment: Your merge doesn't make sense you have ID in df1 which has A and B but in df2 it has C and D also so you're going to get NaN values as you've found. Otherwise there is no real relationship here as the other columns are the same values

Comment: i simplify the scenario. So df2 serves as a reference table and I need all ID to be populated for each Time so that when another column (not in this example, say realdata) in df1 is missing filled with something from table df2 (not in this example either, say proxydata). I need to do this for each Time. later calculation need to be by Time for all IDs.  Hope it is less confusing:).

Comment: not really, you need to update your example to show something that demonstrates your real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is the merge, but rather you need to define what values are missing.  I would do this by making an intermediate dataframe that has all the Time & ID combos you want to be present in the final dataframe:

```
df1a = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1,1,2,2], 'BinID': ['x']*4,
                     'V1': [25, 30, 22, 28], 'ID': ['A','B']*2})

df1b = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1]*4+[2]*4, 'ID': list('ABCD')*2 })

df1 = pd.merge( df1b, df1a, on=['Time','ID'], how='left' )

df1b

  ID  Time
0  A     1
1  B     1
2  C     1
3  D     1
4  A     2
5  B     2
6  C     2
7  D     2
```

The rest of the code is the same and produces:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, on = 'ID', how = 'outer').sort(['Time','ID'])

  BinID_x ID  V2  Time BinID_y  V1
0       x  A  26     1       x  25
2       x  B  26     1       x  30
4       x  C  26     1     NaN NaN
6       x  D  26     1     NaN NaN
1       x  A  26     2       x  22
3       x  B  26     2       x  28
5       x  C  26     2     NaN NaN
7       x  D  26     2     NaN NaN
```